# Using List of <struct> as a datasource to a listview shows object.tostring() instead of DisplayMember

Tags: c#

With a list of struct as the Datasource for a Listbox, I am getting the Object.ToString() rather than the expected field value from the struct

This was working OK when I assigned a DataTable as the DataSource after setting the DisplayMember.

However, I wanted to try using a list of struct (int ID, String Name) instead and despite having set DisplayMember to "Name" before assigning the Datasource to the List I get the row object.toString().

Any help would be fantastic.

On Form Load:

```
    private void frmTestProof_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      TestMaker tm = new TestMaker();

      tm.LoadMakersToListbox(ref lstboxMaker);

    }
```

```
class TestMaker
  {
    public struct MakerRecord
    {
      public int MakerID;
      public String MakerName;

      public MakerRecord(int ID, String Name)
      {
        MakerID = ID;
        MakerName = Name;
      }
    }

    public SQLiteConnection DBconn;
    public String thisPath = "";
    public SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand();

    public DataSet dsMaker = new DataSet();
    public SQLiteDataAdapter daMaker = new SQLiteDataAdapter();

    public TestMaker()
    {
      thisPath = "c:\\sqlite\\abc.db";

      DBconn = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", thisPath));
      DBconn.Open();

      sqlCommand.Connection = DBconn;
      sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    }

    public List<MakerRecord> GetListOfMakers()
    {
      List<MakerRecord> makerList = new List<MakerRecord>();

      String sqlMaker = "SELECT ID, VehicleMakerName FROM VehicleMakers WHERE VehicleMakerName IS NOT NULL"
                          ;
      sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlMaker;
      daMaker.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
      try
      {
        daMaker.Fill(dsMaker, "Makers");

        makerList = (from item in dsMaker.Tables["Makers"].AsEnumerable()
                     select new MakerRecord()
                     {
                       MakerID = Convert.ToInt32(item["ID"]),
                       MakerName = item["VehicleMakerName"].ToString()
                     }).ToList();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("List of Makers - Error ({0})", ex.Message));
      }
      return makerList;
    }

    public void LoadMakersToListbox(ref ListBox lb)
    {
      lb.Items.Clear();
      lb.ValueMember = "MakerID";
      lb.DisplayMember = "MakerName";
      lb.DataSource = GetListOfMakers();
    }
  }
```

[image: The List is being built correctly ...]

[image: What I get ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `public String MakerName;` to `public string MakerName {get;set;}` and `public int MakerID;` to `public int MakerID {get;set;}`

Comment: Of course. Thank you @Tyress..
I really shouldn't try to code at 3am ..... :)

Thank you again.

Comment: @James don't think about it, happens to the best of us :)

Comment: Thanks. :)
If you have time maybe you could check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214435/how-can-i-position-a-listbox-to-an-item-with-a-specific-valuemember for me.