# How can I position a listbox to an item with a specific Valuemember?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selectedindex

I have a winform with a listbox with a datasource of list of struct, where the struct is:

```
    public struct MakerRecord
    {
      public int MakerID { get; set; }
      public String MakerName { get; set; }

      public MakerRecord(int ID, String Name)
      {
        MakerID = ID;
        MakerName = Name;
      }
    }
```

and listbox.ValueMember = "MakerID"
and listbox.DisplayMember = "MakerName"

The user can either select an item and the text (i.e. MakerName) is loaded to a textbox where it can be edited, or click an Add button and get an empty textbox.
After making changes to the textbox, the User clicks a Save button and the record is saved back to Database and the listbox is refreshed - which sets the SelectedIndex = -1.
All good.

But I want to position the listbox back to the record that was edited (or added) and all I have is the MakerID from the db operation.
So how can I set SelectedIndex from just the value member?

Setting SelectedValue (i.e. lstbox.SelectedValue = MakerID) does not effect the SelectedIndex naturally.

Comment: I think it can only be done with a loop.
As it happens I also still have the text of the new or edited name, so I can do listbox.items,indexof(new MakerRecord(MakerID, textbox.text)).  
This works for me in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedItem` property and pick the item you want

Using the struct you provided, here's a quick sample:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbMarkers.DataSource = null;
        var markerList = new List<MarkerRecord>
        {
            new MarkerRecord(1, "first"), new MarkerRecord(2, "second")
        };
        cmbMarkers.ValueMember = "MarkerId";
        cmbMarkers.DisplayMember = "MarkerName";
        cmbMarkers.DataSource = markerList;
        cmbMarkers.SelectedItem = markerList.FirstOrDefault(mr => mr.MarkerId == 2); //second item selected
    }
```

On the last line, you get to choose which item you want selected.